# How to remove linebreak at the end of textarea

Tags: html

I don't understand why there is a line break at the end of this textarea (after `echo random`) even though I haven't put any when creating it. How to get rid of it?

```html
<textarea readonly="" rows="3" style="padding: 10px; resize: none;">
#!/bin/sh

echo random
</textarea>
```

Comment: Is the content of your textarea being created by a script or is this just standard HTML you created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there is a line break at the end of this textarea (after echo random) even though I haven't put any when creating it.

If there was no line break there then `</textarea>` would not be on a new line in the source code.

Remove that new line.

```html
<textarea readonly="" rows="3" style="padding: 10px; resize: none;">
#!/bin/sh

echo random</textarea>
```

Comment: Eh.. was on phone so got a bit late to answer.. will delete mine x)

Comment: Specifying rows doesn't mean that it will limit the lines.. it controls the amount of lines you want to show on load which later can be resized. Its better to use height and width instead.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<textarea readonly="" rows="3" style="padding: 10px; resize: none; overflow:hidden;">
#!/bin/sh

echo random
</textarea>
```